# Is there a way to change a resistor on the PCB?

Tags: pcb, resistors

I have a problem. I am making a PCB design which will be used for different applications.

There is a part of the circuit that, depending on the application of use, will use a different resistor value (three different possible values.) I plan to make a PCB design with three resistors in parallel and soldering the resistor for the application this PCB will be used for. I am also considering using a jumper and then just selecting between already soldered resistors.

Is there a cleaner and better way of solving this problem?

Comment: Use an MCU that selects the right value depending on the application. Without a much more detailed description and a schematic, I doubt this can be properly answered without giving opinions.

Comment: Solder jumper? Variant handling? Regular jumper?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem even is. If you need to solder in an application specific resistor, then have a single empty space for a resistor on PCB and solder in any resistor you want.

Comment: Is this going to be something that you are assembling yourself, or is it done by a subcontractor? How often will this resistor need changing? Will it be used in multiple applications so a different resistor needs switching in often? Or is id application specific with a different device for each, so only 1 resistor fitted? The use of the product can affect the most practical answer

Comment: There is some information missing to properly answer your question. What's the quantity? How and by whom are the boards assembled? What do you mean exactly by "cleaner and better"? Does the value need to change once in production or multiple times in the field? Is your main concern convenience in changing the value or something else like board space and BOM cost?

Answer (score 4):

A header plus shunt (maybe what you mean by 'jumper'), a DIP switch, or a rotary DIP switch are common ways this problem is approached in hardware.

You can also make solder jumpers (half-moon pads that are bridged by solder) if you trust your user near the product with a soldering iron.

As Andy suggests, an EEPROM and firmware can be used, but of course you have to deal with the possiblity of the MCU losing the data or it getting corrupted and whatever consequences that entails, plus it might be complex for the user to set the option if the user interface is primitive.

I have a commercial product that has an edge connector that accepts one of several small PCBs that just contain jumpers (etched conductors from one connector pad to another) . This is intended for HVAC service technicians and intrepid DIY types to use. The PCBs have labels and the product comes with matching labels to mark the enclosure. The main cost is probably the edge connector itself.

Answer (score 3):

From the end user's perspective, it is often best to route all 3 resistors to a connector (like a terminal block), then pick one of the 3 by connecting a wire between it and a 4th pin "common". User-friendly and no soldering required.

As for jumpers, they tend to go missing in action, and they aren't ideal for ESD either. Dip-switches are somewhat more rugged if you ensure to buy a good brand. Beware of non-washable dip-switches in case your assembly contractor washes the boards.

Answer (score 2):

DIP switches, rotary switches and jumpers could be used to select a resistor if all are already onboard. Or just a solder pad to put on a blob of solder to select which resistor is active.

Other than that, just have one single free space for a resistor, and solder in any reaistor you like depending on application.